# How to Write a test cases for Lift Snippets using Specs2

Tags: scala, lift, specs2

This is my Snippet class

```
def register(in:NodeSeq):NodeSeq = {
  val name  = S.param("name")
  val email = S.param("email")
  val password = S.param("password")
  in
}
```

i am new to writing a test cases please give suggestion i am strucking

Comment: What have you tried? And what are you looking to test for? For reference on Lift and specs, you can look at: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/RmHcbCFWx88 and http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#SquerylUnitTest for some thoughts.

Comment: I would say that this is more relevant: http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#TestingReq